# Tableview/ListView in Android SDK (Eclipse IDE) for any kind of schedule

Tags: android, eclipse, listview

I have a problem implementing school schedule in the mentioned IDE for Android. The idea is that a user can set time for classes and they will be shown in that view. Which view to use best? How to connet that?

Any idea what is the best way to try implementing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created schedule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical">

<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
android:clickable="true"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv01"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Monday"
    android:textColor="#000" >
</TextView>
```

And for every textView I created one relativeLayout in which is inserted one listView below the mentioned textView. Every listView is populated from sqllite database, when clicked it invokes new activity which populates database. Hope that help.

Answer (score 0):

On first screen take gridview/table view to select date. 
On second screen show custom listview with date & desecration of for the time slot.
You need to add button to add time in listview. On click on that button show input dialog which take time & descreption,

Hope this is what u r idea is.

Comment: I was thinking more like a static table. First row will have ( Hours, Monday, Tuesday, ...), first column will be hours in range (8am-8pm) with 4 row per hour (15min difference). When the user click on a empty cell of the table, he'll get a window where he can set the school class and time which will, after save button hit, be dynamically shown on that table in the specific range of hours with name of the school class. Any code would be appreciated. And thanks for you fast response rohit.